# Is it OK to lock and use an Entity Framework context in a really complex multi task windows form program?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, entity-framework, task

I have a specific question about EF, but here is the background first.

I inherited some code that has been evolving in complexity for more than ten years and I am moving it slowly to new technologies (Linq, Tasks instead of Threads, asynchronous programming ... etc.), now is the turn to remove DataSets in favor of (asynchronous?) EF.  It is a Windows form with dozens of Tasks.

The specific question is about **where** to declare the EF context in the code since there is conflicting literature about this topic.

Here are the choices that I can think of:

**(1) Is it better to use/discard the context everywhere is required, like this:**

```
using (dbEntities context = new dbEntities()) {
    _ratio = (await context.realtime.SingleAsync(x => x.code == _code)).ratio;
}
```

**(2) Is it better to use the context per task:**

```
using (dbEntities context = new dbEntities()) {
    ... code that does not use the context ...

    _ratio = (await context.realtime.SingleAsync(x => x.code == _code)).ratio;

    ... more code that does not use the context ...

    _orders = await context.realtime.Where(x => x.enter).Select(x => x.oderID);
}
```

**(3) Is it better to declare the context in the form, as static, and use a lock to access it?**

```
... in the global area ...

static public dbEntities context = new dbEntities();  // Declaration and instantiation  
static public object dbEntityLock = new object();

... in the code ...

lock (dbEntityLock) {
    _ratio = (await context.realtime.SingleAsync(x => x.code == _code)).ratio;
}
```

The main difference between (1) and (2) is that each task can take minutes to finish.  Is it OK to have the context open for so long, even though I will ensure calling *context.SaveChanges()* anywhere is required?

The only reason for not going straight to (1)/(2) for safety ness is just performance: the previous developers have built a series of complex global variables (a cache), storing the data calculated by other tasks, so instead of reading from the DB, the logic reads it from some of these variables, but I am sure you can see how complex the code turns into to ensure that the DB and the variables are in sync.  So if possible, I would like to remove that as well, assuming EF has an internal cache for its data, but only option (3) allows me to do so.

If it helps to answer your question, almost all tasks are 'responsible' for only one table in the DB, they do all calculations and store the data in the DB.  Some of the values calculated by a task may need to be used in calculations done by other tasks, hence the use of these global variables instead of constantly querying the DB in all tasks.

Is it safe to use option (3)?  If you agree would you lock on every single access (read/write) or on write access only?

Comment: 1 yes, the longer a context stays open the more problems that can occur, 2 well, maybe, i mean this is a judgment call, don't keep contexts around for excessive amounts of time unless you need to. 3 no absolutely not, this is extremely poor form and bad design. The rule of thumb use them for the shortest amount of time and logic unit of work you can. This is all cached underneath, there is no harm in spinning up new contexts, they are light weight.

Comment: @TheGeneral do you have any link to why is (3) bad?  I kind of agree with you, but I assume that the context implement some sort of internal cache, so the more (1) is used the least use we have for that cache.  Trying to have facts :)

Comment: The longer you keep a context open, the more problems that can happen. Also the more that is created and being tracked, there are plenty of blogs about this. Sorry i don't have a link handy, but it definitely is the consensus. last a dbcontext isnt thread safe, which adds another layer of complexity that is easily solved with 1 or 2.

Comment: The question asked in the title has nothing to do with what you have asked in the post. If your question is really what you've asked in title, then it's off-topic. But if you are asking about some guidelines on lifetime of db context (preferably having some official source) then read the answer which I shared.

Comment: @RezaAghaei, you were right, I have changed the title to express exactly what the question is.

Comment: @MiguelMateo I agree with user "TheGeneral". You should use approach (1) while think carefully about (2) and avoid (3).

Answer (score 1):

There are some general guidelines about [Working with DbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/working-with-dbcontext):

> ### [Lifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/working-with-dbcontext#lifetime)
>
> Here are some general guidelines when deciding on the lifetime of the
> context:
>
> - When working with Web applications, use a context instance per request.
> - When working with Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) or Windows Forms, use a context instance per form. This lets you use
>   change-tracking functionality that context provides.
> - If the context instance is created by a dependency injection container, it is usually the responsibility of the container to
>   dispose the context.
> - If the context is created in application code, remember to dispose of the context when it is no longer required.
> - When working with long-running context consider the following:
>
>   - As you load more objects and their references into memory, the memory consumption of the context may increase rapidly. This may cause
>     performance issues.
>   - The context is not thread-safe, therefore it should not be shared across multiple threads doing work on it concurrently.
>   - If an exception causes the context to be in an unrecoverable state, the whole application may terminate.
>   - The chances of running into concurrency-related issues increase as the gap between the time when the data is queried and updated
>     grows.

Regarding to above guidelines, for a Windows Forms application:

- If you need change tracking in your form, then create an instance of the context per from and use the same context in all the operations.
- Since working with long-running context has some side-effects, if you have a refresh/reload operation in your form, you can create a new instance of context and dispose the previous instance. If you don't need, create the context just when you need it in a using block.
- Don't forget to dispose the instance when disposing your form.
- Also keep in mind, the context is not thread-safe, so do not share it across multiple threads which may work concurrently on it.

Comment: Thanks. This is part of the literature I have found previously that is confusing and obscure: from one angle seems to imply that my solution number (3) is OK, but then implies is not.  Have you had experience using EF in a multi-task environment?  What approach would you suggest?

Comment: No problem. In general you should create the context for shortest possible time frame. Also keep in mind, for tracking changes on an entity set, you are not forced to use a long lived context, instead you can have `INotifyPropertyChanged` implemented for your entities and also use `ObservableCollection` for tracking changes, then create an instance of context and apply changes and save changes, then dispose the context.